# Let V be an inner product space. If $ x⊥y $, then show that

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

> Let $V$ be an inner product space. If   $x_i ⊥ x_j $ when $i\neq j$, then show that
>   $$\Bigg\Vert\sum_{i=0}^n x_i\Bigg\Vert^2\   =\sum_{i=0}^n \Vert x_i \Vert^2. $$

Comment: want to prove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start, I'll do the special case $n=2$,

> $$ ||x_1+x_2||^2=\langle x_1+x_2,x_1+x_2 \rangle=  \langle x_1,x_1 \rangle + \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle + \langle x_2,x_1 \rangle + \langle x_2,x_2 \rangle. $$

Now, using the facts

> i) $\langle x_1,x_1 \rangle=||x_1||^2$,
>
> ii)$ \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle =  \langle x_2,x_1 \rangle =0 $

the desired result follows.

> Try to work out the general case.

**Added:**

> $$\Bigg|\Bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k \Bigg|\Bigg|^2 = \langle \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k ,\sum_{m=1}^{n}x_m\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{m=1}^{n} \langle x_k, x_m \rangle =  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \langle x_k, x_k \rangle =\sum_{k=1}^{n} ||x_k||^2, $$

since $ \langle x_k,x_m \rangle =0,$ for $k\neq m. $

Comment: can u solve u it

Comment: Have you given it a try?

Comment: we need to prove if inner product of x_i is perpendicular to x_j then this norm exist and conversly too

Comment: ur concepts are gud, can u complete the prove its involve iff and only statment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the definition of norm induced by the inner product,and the bilinearity or conjugate bilinearity of inner product

Comment: can u implement this , i need written prove